# ASP.NET MVC 4 Passing Object Variable Through ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html.actionlink

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 application. There is a razor view in my application that works with List type as a model.

```
@model List<MeetingLog.Models.UserModel>

@{
    Layout = null;
}
.
.
.
```

I am iterating through Model variable like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @item.Name
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @item.Surname
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.ActionLink("Click", "SavePerson", "Meeting", new {model = item, type = "coordinator"}, null)
                            @Html.ActionLink("Click", "SavePerson", "Meeting", new {model = item, type = "participant"}, null)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
```

I need to pass two variables to SavePerson action with action links. First one is current UserModel, and second one is string variable named type. But in my action first parameter comes through as null. But string parameter comes correctly. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use ajax calls for this

```
$('.btnSave').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '@(Url.Action("SavePerson", "Meeting"))',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            Value1: 'Value1',
            Value2: 'Value2'
        },
        success: function (result) {
            alert('Save Successful');
        }
    });
});
```

and put the call in a button click or a link click if you want with href = #  hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 4):

You can not pass instances complex types through querystring. This is the way to use it:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click", "SavePerson", "Meeting", new {x = item.x, y = item.y, ..., type = "participant"}, null)
```

Comment: But this is working:
@Html.ActionLink("Click", "SavePerson", "Meeting", item, null). With this format item comes correctly but I can't pass second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You actually can, it's just a little weird, when you are coding the passed values (new{})
what you have to do is pass it as a new object that you are constructing so it ends up being:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link Name", "LinkActionTarget", new Object{model = item, type ='Coordinator'}
```

Where Object is the name of your object, and model and type are attributes of that object