# Editable DropDownList in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-select, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a list of items. I have to provide users an opportunity to edit those values. As I cannot efficiently handle it using textbox(generated dynamically), I was thinking to have dropdownlist which are editable.

Any suggestions?

Comment: on change of the dropdown populate a text box and when they submit do an ajax call back to the controller with the edited value and then you can update the record in the drop down to the changed value (or remove and readd).  see my answer here for the ajax call http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19359204/asp-net-mvc-4-passing-object-variable-through-actionlink/19360998#19360998

Comment: Can you be more specific in how the functionality should work? Have you searched around and found anything that is close to what you want or wouldn't work? I did a quick search and found an [editable dropdown](http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/scripts/form_widget_editable_select/form_widget_editable_select.html). Would an [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) be more stuied?

Comment: @MattBodily in the mentioned approach, I can submit only one value at a time.But I am looking for submitting multiple values at the same time.

Comment: @RowanFreeman I couldn't find anything except one third party widget. But I cannot use that as we have company policy. I'll try the one you proposed and let you know the result.

Comment: @RowanFreeman This what specifically I am looking for. I have list of codes like "1234","5678","5421". Size of list is dynamic. User should be able to edit all these three values and submit. In the controller, I should capture all these three edited values.

Comment: In my approach you can send as many variables as you would like. Just add them to the data attribute

Comment: I am going with the thought of displaying textboxes. Looping though the list and displaying textbox for each item. In my case list count is less than 3-5 values.